# i have to connect multiple hostnames dynamically by using JNDI

Tags: java, jdbc

Please help me,

My problem is to connect multiple hostnames dynamically by using JNDI.
    I am using the JNDI,

```
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) envCtx
                .lookup("jdbc/MYDB");
        con = ds.getConnection();
```

“jdbc/MYDB”  is my JNDI name. it was configured in context.xml file in Tomcat.Like

I have different host address like 1)abc.com 2)xyz.com….
 abc.com have the some users and xyz.com also have the some users
when abc.com users login to my application then “url” must be replaced with abc.com and when xyz.com users login to my application then “url” must be replaced with xyz.com.

Thanks in Advance……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set url through InitialContext properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setPropertyprops.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url)
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
```

what the url should look like depends on the server you are trying to read DataSource from. If it is Tomcat you can hardly achieve that because Tomcat does not provide remote access to JNDI resources

Comment: Can u please give me one example for InitialContext properties. Thank u

Comment: sir i can't apply the given above example code,can u please provide any other example in detail.Thank u.....

Comment: take a look at this http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/08/access-jboss-datasource-remotely-from.html